# Need help for a latin motto - beauty in decay

Tags: motto

need som help putting together a few words for a fun motto for a club / small group of friends who have a common interest especially in british vintage motorcycles, but also in vintage stuff in general.  I would like to put into latin that there is beauty in decay degradation and vintage stuff, and was thinking about something like "Ubi tritus, ibi iucunditas" )(where there is decay, there is delight). Is there anyone who can come up with suggestions or corrections on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly say *ubi tritus, ibi iucunditas*, but it means "where there is wear, there is enjoyment," which is not really what you are asking for.

As for "beauty in decay," when you say your and your friends' interest is vintage things, I assume you mean old technology, furniture, art, etc. which may *show its age*, but does presumably, perhaps even thanks to your efforts, not yet *rot away*. I also assume that you would like to avoid words associated with failing human health like *tabes*.

With this in mind I would suggest:

> Venustas in obsoletis

... which literally means "loveliness, grace, beauty in things that are old, worn out, have fallen into disuse and lost their value." (The verb *obsolescere* encapsulates all these ideas.) Or one could of course simply translate it as "beauty in the obsolete."